# Matrix proofs question.

Tags: linear-algebra

Hi I have some questions for proving matrix. Here is the statement :  $A$ and $B$ are two square matrices of the same size. $I$ is the identity matrix. We suppose that $I + AB$ is invertible of inverse $S$.

> 1) I want to show that $ABS = I - S$
>
> 2) Calculate $(I + BA)BSA$ and show that it's equal to $BA$.
>
> 3) Show that $(I + BA)(I - BSA) = I$

Comment: You mean $I+AB$ is invertible, and $(I+AB)^{-1} = S$, right?

Comment: @NicholasStull yes

Comment: @JohnHughes I did the first by multiplying ABS with (I + AB)^-1 but I didn't get I - S at the end

Comment: Why did you do that? You're supposed to show that $ABS = I-S$, not that $ABS \cdot (I + AB)^{-1} = I - S$.

Comment: I'm lost actually it's my first linear algebra course and i'm doing this for the first time :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $ABS=I-S$ if and only if $S+ABS=I,$ if and only if $(I+AB)S=I,$ which is true.

2) $(I+BA)BSA=(B+BAB)SA=B(I+AB)SA=BIA=BA$.

3) $(I+BA)(I-BSA)=I+BA-(I+BA)BSA=I+BA-BA=I,$ using (2) for the second equality.

Comment: can you explain a little bit what you did for the 2) and 3)?

Comment: Of course. For (2), I right-multiplied $I+BA$ by $B$ to get $B+BAB.$ Then I factored out the $B$ on the left side of this to get $B(I+AB).$ Finally, $(I+AB)S=I,$ by definition of $S$.

Comment: For (3), I distributed $I+BA$ to $I-BSA$ to get $I+BA$ for the first term, and $(I+BA)(-BSA)$ for the second term. Then I used (2) to see that the second term is equal to $-BA.$

Comment: can you solve this please : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461016/elementary-matrix-row-operation-using-identity-matrix

Answer (score 0):

Since $S$ is the inverse of $I + AB$, we have

$(I + AB)S = I; \tag 1$

now,

$((I + AB)S = I) \Longleftrightarrow (S + ABS = I) \Longleftrightarrow (ABS = I - S);  \tag 2$

this proves item (1); next

$(I + BA)BSA = (B + BAB)SA = B(1 + AB)SA$
$= B((I + AB)S)A = BIA = BA, \tag 3$

and so item (2) is proved.  As for item (3),

$(I + BA)(I - BSA) = I + BA -BSA - BABSA = I + BA - B(I + AB)SA =$
$I + BA - B((I + AB)S)A = I + BA - BIA = I + BA - BA = I. \tag 4$

Comment: can you solve this please : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2461016/elementary-matrix-row-operation-using-identity-matrix