# Elementary matrix row operation using identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hi my first question is:

$1)$ I have a matrix $A$ : [Matrix $A$ and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiurM.png) and I want it transform into Matrix B. By using this method shown in this picture [Elementary row operation Using identity matrix][2]. I know we could just invert the lines of A to get B, but I don't want to do it like this. I actually need to multiply by another square matrix that have 1's on diagonal.

2) Deduce that there exists a matrix P which is an elementary matrix product such as B = PA and give this product. I know that multiplying A by it self will give us B but how can I deduce P?

And finally do the opposite of 2) and note that A = P^-1

Here is the example for operation on columns ;  [Columns operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7Gre.jpg)

Comment: (1) is not possible. $\det(A)=-1,$ $\det(B)=1,$ and all of the transformations you are considering have $\det(T)=1,$ so $\det(T_{1}T_{2}\cdots T_{m}A)=-1$ for any sequence of $T_{1},\ldots,T_{m}.$

Comment: For (2), you have $B=I,$ so $PA=I$ implies that $P=A^{-1}=A,$ so it's not clear what needs to be deduced.

Comment: thanks but for the 1) our teacher did an example in class but that was to invert columns. We placed the identity matrix on right hand side but for the row operation the I matrix should be placed on left side.

Comment: Okay but you need to have all of the elementary row operations available to you in order to do this: scalar multiplication of a row, exchanging two rows, and adding a scalar multiple of one row to another. If you limit yourself to only the third class of row operations, you must preserve the determinant.

Comment: I edited the post. check the columns operation. I hope you understand what I  mean before

Comment: You have the same problem if you're operating on columns that you had with rows.

Comment: so that mean we can't transform A into B buy doing this?

Comment: That is what I'm saying. You need either to use a scalar multiplication or a column transposition in order to get to $B$ from $A$.